# Short story describing future communications technology called an uvee

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to remember the name of this short(?) story and author (possibly North American?) where a technology is described to give humans the ability to communicated wirelessly via an implant to the back of the neck called an uvee (which I think was aimed to be an evolution of the acronym T.V.). I can't remember if it was all upper case or not.

The special thing about this implant was that it was supposed to allow thoughts and *feelings* to be communicated - including pleasure and pain. I don't remember this having much of a plot, it could have been an excerpt rather than the full work.

Read it one time maybe about 20-25 years ago from a print out rather than book form. Author may have been a mathematician or something like that (no, not Lewis Carroll!).

Comment: How confident are you that "uvee" is correct?

Comment: Rings a bell. Might be Phillip K. Dick.

Comment: I think I know the story, but what started out as a communication device ended up being used to ask the “collective” questions that got more and more complicated until someone asked something like “how long until the universe ends” and the uvee or whatever spent the next few billion or trillions of years consuming the universe so it could answer that question?

Comment: Thanks heaps guys, I'll check out all these suggestions. To be honest, 20-odd years, who knows if I'm remembering it right.